Template parameters for c++ multidimentional array
Can someone explain how the following base template and specialization is instantiated to produce the correct result? I'm particularly unclear on how the <U[N]> template parameter is interpreted. Is it because the non-type template parameter is recursively referring to the last/outer dimension?
I've seen this template-related question which was pointed out to me as being similar but it doesn't deal with template metafunctions, multidimensional arrays, or recursion.
//The primary template handles scalar (non-array) types as a base case
template <class T> 
struct rank { static size_t const value = 0U; };

//The partial specialization recognizes an array type:
template <class U, size_t N>
struct rank<U[N]> {
    static size_t const value = 1u + rank<U>::value;
};

int main() {
  using array_t = int[10][20][30];
  //yields 3u (at compile time)
  std::cout << "rank is " << rank<array_t>::value << std::endl;
}

This code is from this youtube video on template metaprogramming.

For the type int[10][20][30], U becomes int[10][20] and N is the last 30. For the next "recursion" U is int[10] and N is 20. Then U is int which uses the base structure to "return" 0. So you have essentially rank<int[10][20][30]>::value (from the main function, rank<int[10][20]>::value, rank<int[10]>::value and finally rank<int>::value.

it's recursively instantiating specialized template peeling off one extent at a time until it's  not an array and the primary template gives value 0.

"This code is from this youtube video..." I would recommend using cppinsights for this. Also a c++ book . And Can we see the templates instantiated by the C++ compiler? where this answer mentions cppinsight.

These get instantiated:
struct rank<int> { static size_t const value = 0U; };

struct rank<int[10]> {
    static size_t const value = 1u + rank<int>::value;
};

struct rank<int[10][20]> {
    static size_t const value = 1u + rank<int[10]>::value;
};

struct rank<int[10][20][30]> {
    static size_t const value = 1u + rank<int[10][20]>::value;
};

int main() {
  using array_t = int[10][20][30];
  //yields 3u (at compile time)
  std::cout << "rank is " << rank<array_t>::value << std::endl;
}


Thanks. This very visually helps to clarify what the compiler is doing.  I guess part of my misunderstanding was related to how c++ converts the non-type template argument to an array of fewer dimensions at each iteration. (I was also reminded to try cppinsights for...insights.)
